# Why PyPy fails when I try to define type annotated class member (e.g. list or dict)?

Tags: python, python-typing, pypy

I have following simple code:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Test:
    names: list[str] = field(default_factory=list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Trying to execute it with latest PyPy available via `pyenv` at the moment:

```sh
Python 3.8.12 (9ef55f6fc369, Oct 24 2021, 20:11:54)
[PyPy 7.3.7 with GCC 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)]
```

I receive following error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    @dataclass
  File "test.py", line 6, in Test
    names: list[str] = field(default_factory=list)
AttributeError: type object 'list' has no attribute '__class_getitem__'
```

Same happens basically with any iterable type, e.g. `dict[str, str]` etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hinting a collection of a specified type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853923/type-hinting-a-collection-of-a-specified-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `list` in that way was only introduced in Python 3.9. See [PEP-585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/) for more information. Prior to that you had to import `List` from the `typing` module to use for type hints (unless you just wanted to specify `list` without the contained type).

This means your example would need to be:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Test:
    names: List[str] = field(default_factory=list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Alternatively you can import `annotations` from `__future__` and gain the ability to parameterise `list` when using it in a type hint. Note that this does depend in your tools recognising it as valid and I don't use it personally so I can't guarantee there aren't problems, as per the comments.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Test:
    names: list[str] = field(default_factory=list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Comment: Why suggest using typing.List when you could just use `__future__` import and have sanity of mind?

Comment: @rv.kvetch I was importing `List` before the ability to use `list` was in `__future__`, so that's just the way I do it. Don't know what sanity has to do with it. I'll add that as an option in my answer.

Comment: Using `list[str]` with a `__future__` import breaks [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints), though. Pretty much anything that wants to access the type at runtime will break, unless all it needs is the string form of the annotation.

Comment: It doesn't break most uses of get_type_hints, as it can still resolve it against the function's globals

Comment: @Numerlor: It breaks `get_type_hints` because `get_type_hints` will try to evaluate `list[str]`, and that's going to throw an exception: `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica it's relatively simple to resolve the `get_type_hints` usage though. you can just call it with `localns` object defined as `{'list': typing.List}`. I've tested this in a project before and it should work.

Comment: For more complex evaluation on strings like the new `|` syntax for Union types, you can check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69606986/regex-matching-separated-values-for-union-types) that I added, as I was struggling to find a way to make it work too :-)

Comment: @rv.kvetch: You *can* do that `localns` thing in code you control, but what about code you *don't* control? Any library you use that relies on `typing.get_type_hints` will fail to process this annotation.

Comment: Plus, if your code happens to be a library you're making available for other people, then "code you don't control" includes the entire codebase of anyone who wants to use your library, plus any other libraries they want to use. Then you're making `get_type_hints` very awkward for them to use, and restricting what libraries they can safely use with your code.

Comment: Yep, it's a good point. If a library doesn't specifically check for the Python version and handle those edge cases, they won't get the `get_type_hints` to work. A good example is `pydantic` which unfortunately still requires imports from the `typing` library for Python 3.7+.