# isinstance with string representing types

Tags: python, eval, isinstance

```
isinstance("my string", "str | int")
isinstance("my string", "list")
```

Is there a way to check the type of a variable (`"my string"` in this case) based on a valid type which is stored as a string?

I don't need to import the type, I know it's builtin (int / str / float / etc).

The naive approach would be to call `eval()`, but that's of course unsafe. Is there a safe way to do this other than using regex/string splitting to extract individual types and matching them to their evaluated types in a huge if/else block?

Comment: beware: `eval` for the first one only works in Python 3.10+, which is highly unfeasible.

Comment: see also: [(my) related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69606986/regex-matching-separated-values-for-union-types)

Comment: You don't have a type stored as a string. You have a string which *`mypy`* can interpret as `int | str`. `eval` works because it's a superset of what you want, which is to parse and evaluate a type expression specifically, not an arbitrary Python expression. Depending on where your type-string comes from, it may be safe and perfectly fine to use `eval`.

Comment: @chepner that's not true for modern python. isinstance, for example, accepts built-in type unions natively as of python 3.10, and `int | str` can also be used as a function return signature both when wrapped in quotes (`"int | str"`) and without them. It's as valid a signature as they get, which is why I was expecting there to be a safe built-in way to evaluate it natively.

Comment: (Ultimately, `eval` is what `typing.ForwardRef` uses for the string, which, frankly, concerns me a little. `def f(x: "3+5"): pass`, then `typing.get_type_hints(f)['x'] == 8`.

Comment: @SomeGuy check out my answer below. this is an alternate approach which should hopefully work as well (fastest version I could come up with)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For built-in types, you can do a lookup in the `builtins` module:

```
>>> import builtins
>>> getattr(builtins, 'str')
<class 'str'>
```

And for classes you've defined in your own code there's the `globals()` dictionary:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
...
>>> globals()['Foo']
<class '__main__.Foo'>
```

Note that this doesn't handle union or generic types.

Comment: I was struggling with this until I realized that you need to import `builtins` and access that if you're running code in a module, because your example only works in the interpreter. If you update your answer to account for that I'll accept this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly convoluted way to avoid using `eval` (directly; see below) and using the existing machinery to evaluate the type hint.

```
def foo(x):
    pass

foo.__annotations__['x'] = "str|int"
assert typing.get_type_hints(foo)['x'] == (str|int)
```

Ultimately, `typing.ForwardRef` itself uses `eval` to evaluate `"str|int"` into `str|int`, but either

1. There are safeguards against evaluating arbitrary expression that makes this safer than using `eval` directly, or
2. There are no safeguards, but you'll benefit from any future changes to the `typing` module.

Answer (score 0):

### `fast_eval`

> ***For Python 3.6+***

I would suggest to use the following declaration of `fast_eval` as defined below, which is the fastest possible implementation which can satisfy the ask in the question above.

```py
def fast_eval(val: Any, annotation: str) -> bool:
    cls_name = val.__class__.__name__

    if '|' in annotation:
        for tp in annotation.split('|'):
            if tp.strip() == cls_name:
                return True
        return False

    return annotation.strip() == cls_name
```

Examples:

```py
>>> fast_eval("hey", "int | str")
True
>>> fast_eval("hey", "int | bool")
False
>>> fast_eval("world", "int | list | datetime | BLAH")
False
>>> fast_eval(["world"], "int | list | datetime | BLAH")
True
```

### Performance

Studies show, that it's more than ***10x*** faster than the most *straightforward* implementation of:

> Note: The following works in **Python 3.10+** only!

```py
isinstance("hey", eval("int | str"))
```

Benchmark code:

```py
# Requires: Python 3.10+

import builtins
from datetime import datetime
from timeit import timeit
from typing import Any


def fast_eval(val: Any, annotation: str) -> bool:
    cls_name = val.__class__.__name__

    if '|' in annotation:
        for tp in annotation.split('|'):
            if tp.strip() == cls_name:
                return True
        return False

    return annotation.strip() == cls_name


def eval_with_type(val: Any, annotation: str, __globals=None, t=None) -> bool:
    if __globals is None:
        __globals = {}

    if t is None:
        t = type(val)

    if '|' in annotation:
        for tp in annotation.split('|'):
            if eval_with_type(val, tp, __globals, t):
                return True
        return False

    annotation = annotation.strip()

    try:  # is a BUILTIN? like (str, bool)
        return t is getattr(builtins, annotation)
    except AttributeError:
        # NO, sir! instead, like (datetime, UUID) or user-defined class
        try:
            return t is __globals[annotation]
        except KeyError as k:
            raise TypeError(f'no such type is defined (in globals): {k}')


# asserts
assert True is fast_eval("hey", "int | datetime | str") is eval_with_type("hey", "int | datetime | str", globals())
assert False is fast_eval("hey", "int | datetime | bool") is eval_with_type("hey", "int | datetime | bool", globals())

# timings
print('fast_eval:       ', timeit('fast_eval("hey", "int | datetime | str")', globals=globals()))
print('eval_with_type:  ', timeit('eval_with_type("hey", "int | datetime | str", globals())', globals=globals()))
print('eval:            ', timeit('isinstance("hey", eval("int | datetime | str", globals()))', globals=globals()))
```

Results on my Mac OS:

```
fast_eval:        0.3017798329819925
eval_with_type:   1.1461862919968553
eval:             3.5175461250473745
```